# Solve an autonomous differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solving the differential equation
$y'' = -\frac{y'}{y^7}$,

with initial conditions,
$y(0)=1,y'(0)=\frac{1}{6}$

This DE is not the standard second order linear DE, neither is it separable. So I really don't have any clue on how to approach this. I would appreciate any hint or suggestion. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Integrate both sides to get,
$$y' = \dfrac{1}{6y^6}$$
(note that we put $x=0$ both sides and used initial conditions to find that the constant of integration is zero.) Again rearrange and integrate,
$$\int y^6\mathrm dy = \int \dfrac{\mathrm dx}6\\
\implies \dfrac{y^7}{7} = \dfrac x6+\dfrac17$$
(note that we again used initial conditions to find the constant of integration)